# Получение доступа к переменной дескриптора

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос по работе с дескрипторами.
Не могу понять как получить доступ к self.dct в коде ниже:

```
class C(object):

    def __init__(self,name,value=None):
        self.dct  = {}
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if self.value:
            self.dct[self.name] = self.value
            self.value = None
        return self.dct[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.dct[self.name] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del self.dct[self.name]

class A(object):
    c = C('c',10)

z = A()
print(z.c)
```

Получается только если вывести self.dct из **init** тогда dct доступен через C.dct, однако, как вызвать его если он записан в **init** понять не могу.

Так же вопрос - когда я выношу self.dct из **init** и объявляю его просто как dct - почему в **get** и прочих функциях он все равно остается доступен через self.dct?

```
print(A.c.dct) #AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dct'
print(z.c.dct) #AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dct'
```

Comment: A.c.dct не работает что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Если dct инициализируется в init, то получить к нему доступ можно только после создания экземпляра класса(и соответственно его инициализации). А при выносе dct из init, dct - все равно свойство класса(по этому и self.dct), только уже доступен через C.dct, так как инициализируется при создании класса, а не его экземпляра.

Comment: Экземпляр класса создается вот здесь `c = C('c',10)` как мне потом вывести dct - вот что я не могу сообразить.

Comment: @Vova, никак. Вы переопределили метод `__get__` класса `C`.  Теперь при запросе знаения `A.c` будет возвращатся 10 (то что указано в теле класса `A`). Это целое число, а у него, понятное дело, нет свойства `dct`.

Answer (score 0):

Простите, если не так понял как вы представляете себе работу дескрипторов, но, на всякий случай поясню.
Экземпляр класса **C** в вашем примере создается один единственный. Это происходит в момент создания класса **A**.

```
z1 = A()
z2 = A()
z1.c  # вызовет: A.c.__get__(self=A.c, instance=z1, owner=A)
z2.c  # вызовет: A.c.__get__(self=A.c, instance=z2, owner=A)
A.c   # вызовет: A.c.__get__(self=A.c, instance=None, owner=A)
```

Именно по наличию непустого значения в аргументе **instance** обычно определяют как происходит обращение к атрибуту: через класс или через его экземпляр.
Если иногда нужно получать именно объект класса **C**, геттер обычно дополняют так:

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    if instance is None:
        # этот кусочек выполнится, если к атрибуту обратились через класс
        return self

    # А здесь код, выполняющийся при вызове через экземпляр
```

Этот прием часто нужен во всяких ORM и ODM, когда у свойств есть, например, свои методы и к ним нужно обращаться тоже.

Что вы хотели добиться своим кодом мне не очень понятно. Если вы хотите что-то сохранить через свойство в контексте объекта класса **A**, то в таких случаях обычно хранят значения в словаре в скрытом атрибуте внутри объекта класса.

```
class MyProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, name, default):
        self.name = name
        self.default = default

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        return instance._hidden_storage.setdefault(self.name, self.default)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance._hidden_storage[self.name] = value


class MyClass(object):
    my_property = MyProperty('my_property', 13)

    def __init__(self):
        self._hidden_storage = {}


ex1 = MyClass()
ex2 = MyClass()

print ex1.my_property  # 13
ex1.my_property = 10
print ex1.my_property  # 10
print ex2.my_property  # 13
```

Ещё раз. Экземпляр MyProperty создается явно в декларации класса. Это значит, что потомки этого класса имеют доступ к тому же экземпляру.
Пример, где мне захотелось бы в нем (свойстве) хранить некое состояние, которое должно меняться при чтении соответствующего атрибута из объекта... я не смог придумать.